# optionals with get and set

Tags: swift, swift3

Hello I been researching the proper way to implement this and I found multiple articles but not the best correct way to implement this. Lets say I have a variable test, which is an optional and I would like to add some getters and setters. The problem that I have is the variable will be nil when the view loads, but I keep getting an error right on the get function that says: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. I know the reason why I am getting this but also the system will not allow me to just add a setter by itself, any ideas to work with this? Thank you for your help

code:

```
var test: String? {
    get {
     return self.test
    }
    set {
        //some logic
        test = logic response
    }
}


override func viewdidload(){
    super.viewdidload()
    //some logic
    test = newValue
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has many syntax errors :)

However you are not looking for a getter & setter, what you want is the `willSet` observer.

```
class Controller: UIViewController {

    var test: String? {
        willSet {
            // custom logic
            self.test = newValue
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        test = "my value"
    }
}
```

Comment: @appzYouLife Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed! and I apologize I was writing the example on the fly haha thank you again tho!